# Access Azure table storage via OData endpoint

Tags: silverlight, wcf-data-services, odata, visual-studio-2012, azure-table-storage

I would like to access Azure Table Storage via OData endpoint.

All the examples that I have seen to expose an OData endpoint are using SQL Azure or SQL Server, using WCF RIA by creating a Domain Service Class and checking off "Expose OData endpoint" checkbox. The other way is when adding a "WCF Data Service" class. Since I am using Azure Table Storage, I don't have a model (.edmx) to accomplish this.

What are the best practices for handling this situation? I need to access Azure Table Storage via OData endpoint for it to be consumed in several client applications, including Silverlight.

I am using Visual Studio 2012, ASP.NET Framework 4.5, Silverlight 5, C#.

If someone can point me to the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Azure Table Storage is exposed via OData by default, is it just a matter of hooking it up?

Comment: Thank you Jim. I just figured it out. I followed this sample code, and I got it working. Here's the link: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/silverlight/CSAzureTableStorageWCFDS-2355159b

Comment: @Daniel Hey Daniel! I have similar issue. Could you please share some of your code. I have been stuck on implementing this from quite some time.